# How to convert SOLR URL into a Solarium query?

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I have a SOLR URL like this:

```
select?omitHeader=false&wt=json&json.nl=flat&q=*:*&start=0&rows=240&fl=id,*,score&q.op=AND&df=someField&sort=sorting_field desc&fq=status:(active)&fq=someField:(alfa romeo 159)
```

How can I convert it to a Solarium Query object (object of class `\Solarium\QueryType\Select\Query\Query`)?

Or is it possible to execute such URL using `\Solarium\Core\Client\Client`?